# How do I "Read" XML from Internet in Visual Basic .NET?

Tags: xml, vb.net

So I'm creating a program in Visual Basic 2010 that will be going through about 1.2 million XML files from the internet. The URL of each file is in the following format:

website.com/xmlfeed.action?number=VARIABLE

where "VARIABLE" is a number between 1 and 1.2 million. Once I have the document, I need one specific value from the XML. The relevant section of the document tree is in the following format:

```
<XMLResponce>
 <SectionA>
   <SectionB>
    <Value> 250 </Value>
  </SectionB>
 </SectionA>
</XMLResponce>
```

where the data I need to extract is in "Value".

I spent awhile searching the web today, but came up empty handed. Everything I found was either irrelevant or FAR too complex for me to understand. I think the problem is that I'm not familiar with the terminology associated with XML.

I'd really appreciate an easy-to-understand solution or a link to an easy-to-understand solution. If it's not too much trouble, please explain how it works because I'm trying to learn.

Answer (score 2):

To download a copy of the file you can use HttpWebRequest. You can put calls to GetResponse (or BeginGetResponse if you would prefer them to be asynchronous) in a loop where you generate the URL based on an incrementing Integer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx

To parse the file there are lots of options but Linq to Xml is probably a good bet.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

```
Dim requestPrefix = "website.com/xmlfeed.action?number="

For documentNumber = 1 To 1200000
    Dim request = WebRequest.Create(requestPrefix & documentNumber)
    request.Timeout = 5000
    Dim response = request.GetResponse()

    Using stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim xDocument = XDocument.Load(stream)

        'Use Linq to Xml to get the value you are after from the XDocument.
    End Using
Next
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still totally lost.

Comment: How far are you getting. Are you able to download the files?

Comment: Just to be clear: I don't need to download them as in moving to local storage, just fetch the values.

Comment: This is a bit more complicated. You will at some point need some logic to parse XML. If that logic is remote from the files themselves, then you will need to get the content of the files to that logic - in other words download it. If you know that the elements that you are interested in are toward the begining of the files then you could use XmlReader.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx
If you know at least roughly the position of those elements within the file then you could use the AddRange method as described here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440999

Comment: I thought you were suggesting a method to permanently save each file. I understand I need to download the files to parse them, but they can simply be dumped after that.

Comment: In that case, you should be able to take the Stream object that you get from the HttpWebRequest.GetResponse method and pass it to the XDocument.Load method without it ever being saved to disk.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349.aspx

Comment: I thing I need help with is how to load an XML document from a URL and assign the value of a unique tag to a variable. That can't be very hard, right?

Comment: I added some code to get you started. I am on my mobile so it is not well formatted and may contain errors. Let me know once you have XDocuments being populated.

Comment: I think I have to code to assign the value to a string from the first document, but the program hangs when it reaches XDocument.Load. Throws the exception "Unhanded exception has occurred in your application. The request was aborted: the operation timed out."

Comment: I have modified the code to allow a timeout to be supplied. I would first check using a browser that the files are available. Pasted the URL into Internet Explorer for example and confirm that the file is downloaded correctly. Also note how long this takes.

Comment: I'll try your new code. And yes, the files load in 1-2 seconds.

Comment: Sorry to hear that it is still not working. Put a breakpoint on the call to GetResponseStream. Check the value of the request.RequestUri property and confirm that the Url works in your browser.

Comment: I thought the whole point of XML was to store data in a format that could be used easily.

Comment: You haven't really started working with XML yet. The problems that you have had so far have been with downloading files. If you look at the code supplied in the answers here you should see that it is not actually that involved. You just need to do some debugging.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with VB, but I can't seem to load any XML. So, I switched to JavaScript. Just tested first 10 documents, works great. Thanks for your help anyway, I'm sure your code would have worked perfectly. ;)

Comment: That is a bit disappointing but I can understand that you want to make some progress on this. Better luck next time.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ to XML in VB makes this quite painless. The following is not tested, so YMMV:

```
Dim values = From index in Enumerable.Range(1, 2100000)
             From doc in XDocument.Load(New Uri("http://website.com/xmlfeed.action?number=" & index))
             Select value in doc...<Value>.FirstOrDefault()
```

This will give you an IEnumerable with the first value node in each xml. Depending on the size of your XML, you may need to alter this method because XDocument.Load does load the entire xml document into memory before processing.

Comment: @Josh: he just gave you the answer.