# Reading a Xml file in html through web services

Tags: html, xml, web-services, visual-studio-2010

How do I parse and read an XML file in an HTML page through a web service using Visual Studio. I need the XML file to be declared globally, so that anyone can access the corresponding XML.

Comment: See my answer to this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783697/how-do-i-read-xml-from-internet-in-visual-basic-net/6783849#6783849